# Tight lower bound for logarithm function

Tags: functions, logarithms

Is there a lower bound for the logarithm function which is tighter than,
$$\log(x)\geq 1-x^{-1}$$
that works for all real values of $x>0$?

Comment: What sort of functions are you allowing in the lower bound?

Comment: Unless you restrict allowable functions, $g(x) = \dfrac12 - \dfrac1{2x} + \log \sqrt{x}$ trivially gives you a better bound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get one possible family of better bounds, consider any $\alpha \in (1, 2)$.  We have
$$t > 0 \implies \int_1^x \frac{dt}t \geqslant \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t^\alpha} \implies \log x \geqslant \frac{1-x^{1-\alpha}}{\alpha-1} = g(\alpha)$$

For e.g. $\alpha = \frac32$ gives $\displaystyle \log x \geqslant \underbrace{2-\frac2{\sqrt x}}_{g(\frac32)} \geqslant \underbrace{1-\frac1x}_{g(2)}$.